# NLTK Verbnet giving wrong class

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to understand nltk Verbnet api.
Specifically, consider:

```
from nltk.corpus import verbnet
verbnet.classids(lemma='add')
```

The last command prints: `['mix-22.1-2']`.
The method `classids` is supposed to "return only VerbNet class identifiers for classes that contain that lemma as a member".

Now, if go on [the official verbnet project page](https://verbs.colorado.edu/verb-index/search.php) and search for the verb 'add', I get the following:
[image: search result for verb add on verbnet page]
That is, the verb `add` is a member of `mix`, `multiply`, `say`, `addict` and `illustrate`. And the verbnet class is actually `addict`.

**Question:** How do I use nltk to obtain the actual classes related to the verb `add` (and others)?

There seems to be some concepts not very clearly defined (and that I probably do not understand well) that conflict with each other. Thanks for helping! :D

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the misalignment between the results is due to the current version of NLTK usage of Verbnet 2.1 instead of the more recent Verbnet 3.3.

Although not yet officially supported, it is possible to load the recent version of Verbnet with NLTK. To do so:

First, go to [this NLTK Github page](https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/tree/gh-pages/packages/corpora) and download the file `verbnet3.zip`;

Second, Unzip the file in the corpora folder of the NLTK folder data, usually something like: `Users/username/nltk_data/corpora/your_unzip_here`. When you unzip it you should have a folder called `verbnet3` inside the `corpora` folder. This is where nltk will look for the data;

Third, load Verbnet3 in Python with the command:

```
import nltk
vnet3 = nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader('verbnet3', nltk.corpus.reader.verbnet.VerbnetCorpusReader,r'(?!\.).*\.xml')
```

Then you can use `vnet3.classids('add')` to correctly recover the classes `mix`, `multiply` and `say`.